# How to get selected index when used to Ctrl+A key to select rows in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I get the row index or record Position of all items in gridData.SelectItems property.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedItems` Contains actual data (ViewModel) from the collection bound to datagrid's `ItemSource`. Therefore you can obtain the index in that collection for every item selected.

Answer (score 0):

if its a datagridview on winforms then this would work

```
List<int> rowIndexs = new List<int>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in gridData.SelectedRows)
{
     rowIndexs.Add(item.Index);
}
```